# Overriding didSet

Tags: swift, properties

I want to override the property observer and calling the "super.didSet". Is that possible?

```
class Foo {
    var name: String = "" { didSet { print("name has been set") } }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override var name: String = "" { 
        didSet { 
            print("print this first")
            // print the line set in the superclass
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output you want  to see from these print(...)s?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have tried your code in a playground and got and error

> Variable with getter/ setter cannot have and initial value.

So I just removed `=""` from the orverriding variable. like below:

```
class Foo {
    var name: String = "" { didSet { print("name has been set") } }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override var name: String  {
        didSet {
            print("print this first")
            // print the line set in the superclass
        }
    }
}

let bar = Bar()
bar.name = "name"
```

and that's what I got in consol:

```
name has been set
print this first
```